# How to use where in LINQ with json column postgreSQL

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have this kind of model.

```
public class Person
{
    Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // This has jsonbType
    public List<long> FriendsIds { get; set; }
}
 modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Property(e => e.FriendsIds)
                .HasColumnType("jsonb")
                .HasConversion(
                    v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v ?? new List<long>()),
                    v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<long>>(v));
```

And I want to write query to get people which have specific Friends. For example something like this:

```
var friendIds = new List<long>;
var people = await Context.People.Where(x => x.FriendsIds.Intersect(friendIds).Any()).ToListAsync();
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

why you use Intersect?

I want to write query to get people which have specific Friends - **one to many relationship**

class design

```
// One-To-Many Relatioship
public ICollection<long> FriendsIds { get; set; }
```

// and One-To-Many relationships from Person-To-FriendsIds

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
                    .WithMany(c => c.FriendsIds) // One-to-Many
                    .HasForeignKey(f => f.FriendsIds_Id); // Foreign Key
```

Comment: Actually, I have much more complex table structure, and I have to use json format and not one to many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I have much more complex table structure - then use object

```
public class ResourceRoot
{
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public object FriendsIds { set; get; }
}
```

object is better for any complex structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonContains function.

```
var ids = new long[] {1,2,3 };
var friends = _context.Persons.Where(p => EF.Functions.JsonContains(p.FriendsIds, ids)).ToArray();
```

More information [here](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cpoco)

Comment: Thank you, It`s work but not properly. I need to get people which have in friends ids ANY of ids. But you query return people wich contains all ids.

Comment: Then I suggest using **raw sql**: `_context.Persons.FromSqlRaw(
            "select * from "Persons" p where p."FriendsIds" @> ANY('{{6,4,3}}');").ToArray();`